# Best way to feature/branch development

Tags: php, docker, gitlab

very first question.

What is best way to create docker-compose.yml for every branch commited to gitlab?

My idea is to generate docker-compose.yml for all branches included in repository, so each branch will be accessible by url like branch.site.XYZ.

So each branch will be testable indepedently of others, but what is the "best" way to generate that docker-compose.yml. Should i use some git hook? So after commit, some docker-compose.test.yml will be generated (with all branches) and commited along current commit? Generated docker-compose.test.yml will be behind some proxy, which will route request to containers, based on hostname?

So if i have 3 branches, 3 docker images will be build and all 3 images (containers) will be accessible by different hostnames ({branch[1-3].site.XYZ}.

I am beginner in this area (git/docker/gitlab), can you recommend some way to do this?

I want to create branch for every new feature, this feature should be testable on unique subdomain (like abc.site.XYZ), then merged into master and released.

I am alone now, but sometimes different features should be made, so i need something like per branch development with testing. Do you have some ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not ideal for this site, please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I would recommend creating the `docker-compose.yaml` in your *build tool*, for PHP there is Phing, I believe.